# numpy matrix checkboard pattern change

Tags: python, numpy

Hi I'm trying to create matrix with checkboard pattern where, the first [0,0] index values is 1. Currently I was able to create this matrix:

```
Z = np.zeros((8,8),dtype=int)
Z[1::2,::2] = 1
Z[::2, 1::2] = 1
print(Z)

[[0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1]
 [1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0]
 [0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1]
 [1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0]
 [0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1]
 [1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0]
 [0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1]
 [1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0]]
```

But I would like it to be in this manner:

```
[[1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0]
 [0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1]
 [1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0]
 [0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1]
 [1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0]
 [0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1]
 [1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0]
 [0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1]]
```

Comment: Maybe : `Z[::2,::2] = 1; Z[1::2, 1::2] = 1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you suggest, one way to do this is to allocate the ones and set the zeros in the matrix:

```
Z = np.ones((8, 8), dtype=np.int)
Z[1::2, ::2] = Z[::2, 1::2] = 0
```

The other way, as suggested by @divakar, is to get your indices fixed up:

```
Z = np.zeros((8, 8), dtype=np.int)
Z[1::2, 1::2] = Z[::2, ::2] = 1
```

Comment: @AlexT please select this answer if it answers the question to your satisfaction.

Answer (score 0):

From what I've tried and somehow succedeed, I did this:

```
Z = np.zeros((8,8),dtype=int)
Z[1::2,::2] = 1
Z[::2, 1::2] = 1
Z[Z==0]=2
Z[Z==1]=0
Z[Z==2]=1
print(Z)




 [[1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0]
 [0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1]
 [1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0]
 [0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1]
 [1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0]
 [0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1]
 [1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0]
 [0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1]]
```

Put maybe there is more efficient way to do this?

Comment: You are right that this is inefficient since you swap all the values in the array using a temporary value. I've shown you a simpler way that requires no swapping in my answer.